# How to integrate Apache Nifi with Amazon Athena?

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-nifi, amazon-athena

My Requirements:
1. User's will run the sql queries through Apache nifi to Amazon S3.

Is this possible to achieve Nifi integration with Amazon Athena?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to easily integrate Apache NiFi and Amazon Athena.  The NiFi capabilities to leverage/plug-in JDBC drivers and reuse that context in many areas helps here greatly.  See here for info on the JDBC drivers with Athena https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/connect-with-jdbc.html and here for using some of NiFi's DBCP facilities https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-dbcp-service-nar/1.5.0/org.apache.nifi.dbcp.DBCPConnectionPool/index.html

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to by using a combination of an ExecuteStreamCommand and the awscli. The cli has the capabilities to issue Athena queries